# Clarification on bokeh's callback

Tags: python, bokeh

A callback function in *bokeh* usually has three arguments: `attr`, `old`, and `new` as shown in this example in the [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#callbacks)

```
def my_text_input_handler(attr, old, new):
    print("Previous label: " + old)
    print("Updated label: " + new)

text_input = TextInput(value="default", title="Label:")
text_input.on_change("value", my_text_input_handler)
```

My questions are:

1. Why isn't `attr` used inside the body of the function
   `my_text_input_handler`? What (`attr`) is it actually?
2. What is the parameter `"value"` in the method
   `text_input.on_change("value"...)`?
3. After running the curdoc(), a text box with a value ("default") was displayed. I then changed that value ("default") to "test", nothing was printed out whilst I thought 2 sentences "Previous label: default" and "Updated label: test" would be produced.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> All widgets have an .on_change method that takes an attribute name and one or more event handlers as parameters. These handlers are expected to have the function signature, (attr, old, new), where attr refers to the changed attribute’s name, and old and new refer to the previous and updated values of the attribute.

1. `attr` isn't used inside the body of the function my_text_input_handler because it doesn't rely on or do anything with the data. All of the callbacks **share the same signature**, `func(attr, old, new)`, and this example just doesn't do anything with `attr`. Short answer for why it isn't used: no particular reason...

You could easily rewrite it like so:

```py
def my_text_input_handler(attr, old, new):
    print("attr: " + attr)
    print("Previous label: " + old)
    print("Updated label: " + new)
```

`attr` corresponds to "value" in `text_input.on_change("value", my_text_input_handler)`.

2. The "value" parameter passed to the `text_input.on_change` function is the name of the `text_input` attribute that you are watching. So, every time the "value" attribute changes of the `text_input` object, the callback function (`my_text_input_handler`) is invoked with with attribute name ("value") and the old and new values.

Take a look at this HTML/Javascript example to better understand what it is doing: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange2

Here is an example that will help illustrate what the callback is doing. Save this code as "demo.py", run it via `bokeh serve demo.py` and check out how it works.

```py
''' 
Use the ``bokeh serve`` command to run the example by executing:

    bokeh serve demo.py

at your command prompt. Then navigate to the URL

    http://localhost:5006/demo

in your browser.

'''

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import TextInput

def my_text_input_handler(attr, old, new):
    print("attr: " + attr)
    print("Previous label: " + old)
    print("Updated label: " + new)

text_input = TextInput(value="default", title="Label:")
text_input.on_change("value", my_text_input_handler)

curdoc().add_root(text_input)
```

3. Check your terminal/command line for the output, not your browser's javascript console.

Your original code should indeed print:

```
Previous label: default
Updated label: test
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Kapocsi. I'm still confused about `attr`. is it the shorthand for *attribute*? If so, is it related to the `text_input` attribute that was mentioned in point 2 of your reply? Could you please give an example (with actual values) when explaining those concepts so that I could follow? When running the code (with your suggested function which had `print("attr: " + attr)`), it showed a text box with a value ("default"). I then changed that value to "test" but nothing was printed out (as I wanted to see what `attr` was). Why is that?

Comment: Yes, attr is shorthand for attribute or attribute name. It corresponds directly to "value" in this call: `text_input.on_change("value", my_text_input_handler)`. I added a clear example to my original post.

Comment: Thanks, Kapocsi. That was exactly the code I tested before your added example. But as I said, when changed the value "defaut" to "test" in the text box, nothing was printed out!

Comment: You have to click outside the text box for it to register. I just tried it with the code I posted above and it works.

Comment: Ah, I thought the sentences would be printed in the web where the text box was, didn't realise they were shown up in the anaconda prompt! Thanks. Still, it's odd to specify an argument (`attr`) but not utilised it in the function!

Comment: Bokeh calls the provided callback with three arguments, so your callback handler needs to define three arguments (here called attr, old and new). Alternatively you could use a lambda if you really dislike one used argument: `text_input.on_change("value", lambda attr, old, new: my_handler(old, new))` but of course you now have a lambda function which doesn't use all its arguments.